# timeline scroll in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-5.3

```
<script type="text/babel">
    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                listmasters: [],
                listmastersscrolls: [],
                scrollPosition: null,
                scrollPosition1: null
            }
        },

        mounted: function () {
            this.getListMasters();
            window.addEventListener('scroll', this.updateScroll);
            window.addEventListener('scroll', this.updateScroll1);
        },

        methods: {
            getListMasters: function () {
                this.$http.get('/get-listMaster?').then((response) => {
                    this.$set(this, 'listmasters', response.data.data.data);
                });
            },

            updateScroll() {
                this.scrollPosition = window.scrollY;
                this.scrollPosition1 = 950;
            },

            updateScroll1() {
                if (window.scrollY > this.scrollPosition1) {
                    this.$http.get('/get-listMaster1?').then((response) => {
                        this.$set(this, 'listmastersscrolls', response.data.data.data);
                    });
                }
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

everytime i scroll there about 20 requests going to the backend i have to limit this to 0 requests i had to fetch timeline posts  3 by 3. and i have succesfully completed it but for each and every scroll the amount of requests going to the backend is high

Comment: Use a debounce function.

Comment: What Bert said. Firing an XHR request on scroll is a horrible idea as it ends with multiple scroll handler calls depending on the user interaction